# Display File from Google Drive in our Website in gmail-styled UI

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to display a file from google drive to the user on my website.I have already searched and found that we can use the link of google drive file with corresponding {FILE_ID} to use it on our site.But I want to display the file to user in **Gmail-Styled UI** where the file contents can be viewed on the page itself.Do Google provide any API for this kind of display? Or is there any other way to do it? Please Help me.Any suggestions would be highly helpful.